# Integrating ValidForm Builder with Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, validform

I have successfully used ValidFormBuilder to create a safe web form. Hurray for this great tool!
Now I want to use the ValidForm inside a website that is based on Twitter Bootstrap.

I would really like it I could style the ValidForm elements using the Twitter Bootstrap CSS. I can imagine this should be done by adding CSS-classes to the ValidForm-elements.

How can this be done?

More specifically:

1. How can I set the `role`-attribute of the `<form>` element to `form`?
2. How can I add the class `form-control` to the `<input>` elements?
3. How can I add the classes `btw` and `btn-default` to the `<input type="submit">` element?

I would like to create a form that uses the Twitter Bootstrap Forms CSS mentioned here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add classes `btw` and `btn-default` to a button:

#### Add custom class to ValidFrom Builder button:

```
$objForm->addButton(
    "Button label",
    array(
        // Set for example a Twitter Bootstrap class on this button
        "fieldclass" => "btn btn-large"
    )
);
```

*I got this example straight from [the documentation](http://validformbuilder.org/docs/classes/ValidFormBuilder.Button.html)*

#### Add custom attributes to text field

```
$objForm->addField(
    "first-name",
    "First name",
    ValidForm::VFORM_STRING,
    array(),
    array(),
    array(
        // Prefixing meta keys with 'field' will make sure
        // this meta is applied in the <input> element instead
        // of it's wrapping <div>
        "fieldrole" => "example-role"
    )
);
```

#### This will output:

```
<div class="vf__optional">
    <label for="first-name">First name</label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="first-name" id="first-name" class="vf__string vf__text" role="autocomplete">
</div>
```

When you want to add a custom class to the submit element, you'll need some javascript. This will be addressed in the upcoming 4.0 release of ValidForm Builder.

#### Adding data attributes to form element

*Assuming you're in the correct namespace etc.:*

```
$objForm = new ValidForm("formName", null, null, array("data" => array("role" => "cool-role")));
```

This should output something close to:

```
<form ... data-role='cool-role'>
```

Comment: This works like a charm for input and button elements. Is it also possible To add attributes to The Form element?

Comment: @JorritSpee At this point, you can only add a `data` array to the form object. I've updated my answer with an example.